# How can I run a jupyterlab notebook as root?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, jupyter-notebook

How can I run a jupyterlab notebook as root?

I am using a JetBot running on Ubuntu and my goal is to detect in the browser, if one of the [w,a,s,d] keys were pressed to react to it(drive the robot), like in a game.

I used this codesnippet:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    try: 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):  
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            robot.forward(0.3)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("s"):
            robot.backward(0.3)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
            robot.left(0.3)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("d"):
            robot.right(0.3)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        
        else:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

The error was :**You must be root to use this library on linux.**

How can I run a jupyterlab notebook in the browser as root?

Answer (score 0):

There'll be two situations in this:

1. Either directly use root
2. Use a normal user with permissions to execute the command.

The command is:

```
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

or

```
jupyter-notebook --allow-root
```